# n to n grid coming read only Dynamics CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I placed a n:n grid of contact entity on leaseapplication custom entity, which already have 1:n grid of contact also. So, new n:n grid is coming read only.Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a security role issue.  In order to associate contacts with leaseapplications your user must have append permissions on both entities.

It appears that you must also have create permission on the child entity (so if you are on a leaseapplication you must have create privilege on contact in order to create a new N:N relationship).  Microsoft has recognized this as a bug.  Read more [here](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/119729.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions

1. Apply most recent Update Rollup 3/2 
   or
2. Provide required create/append/append to privileges for both entities to avoid this issue.

obviously my recommendation is to move ahead with the Update Rollup which will fix many other issues.

Thank you.